# AWS SWF - activities client generation not working (Maven, IntelliJ)

Tags: amazon-web-services, client, amazon-swf

I'm working through the SWF tutorial right now and trying to get GreeterActivitiesClient in GreeterWorkFlowImpl. I'm getting "Cannot resolve symbol" error for the Client and the ClientImpl. Per the AWS materials, I thought these would be generated from the annotations in the Activities class, which I have. Any ideas?

Dependencies in my pom.xml, (taken from the materials):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-swf-build-tools</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The  SWF guide I'm using:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/setup.html#installing-maven

Comment: Please point to the doc you are following to work with Java and SWF.

Comment: Also - what you are trying to do. If you want to create a workflow in the Cloud - you should look at using AWS Step Functions over SWF.

Comment: @smac2020    Hi, thanks for commenting! I added a link of the tutorial I'm following. As for what I'm trying to do...I'm just trying to follow along in their tutorial    :'(

Comment: look at temporal.io as well

Answer (score 0):

That is old content. If you want to work with SWF and Java - look at V2 content here - including the POM dependencies.

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/example_code/swf

Better yet, if you want to build workflows on the AWS Cloud, consider using [AWS Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/welcome.html).

There is a Java V2 AWS Step Functions tutorial here that walks you through how to create a workflow that interacts with other AWS Services.

[Create AWS serverless workflows by using the AWS SDK for Java](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_workflows_stepfunctions)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I took the bom from the pom.xml to see if that was what I was missing but it didn't resolve my client error. Do you have any inkling as to why the ActivitiesClient can't be resolved when I have the @Activities annotation in my activities class?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issues running this tutorial with Maven. My pom.xml looked exactly the same.

I did two things to fix this issue:

1. Go to settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Annotation Processors. Check **Enable annotation processing**
2. Add maven-compiler-plugin to your pom.xml (latest at the time of writing). Such as:

   `

   ```
       <build>
           <plugins>
               <plugin>
                   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>3.5.1</version>
                   <configuration>
                       <source>1.8</source>
                       <target>1.8</target>
                   </configuration>
               </plugin>
           </plugins>
       </build>
   ```

   `

Go ahead and run a build, the client classes should appear. I hope this helps.